# WordPress Plugin-Facebook Comment (not detected)

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Please help me I can't change language my facebook plugin.

WordPress Plugin-Facebook Comment Can not detect the language of those who go with what the settings FBю

He showed only in english , need change to Azeri (az_AZ)

Please help me, I want to fb plugin it self changed the language plug-in for he lacation.

If my facebook account settings in Azeri Language, also auto change Plugin in Azeri Language,If Russia ,Plugin also in Russian, If English ,Plugin also in English, Please help me for add section to my facebook comments plugin , for auto detected location language and show menu and items in that language